# Meteor Router.go not passing params

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Snippet of code client-side:

```
Template.projectEditButton.events({
  "click .edit": function() {
    Router.go('projectForm', {prjId: this._id});
  }
});
```

At this point, this._id is correct. In router file:

```
Router.route('/projects/form', {
  name: 'projectForm',
  data: function() {
    return Projects.findOne(this.params.prjId);
  }
});
```

this.params is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: What does the url look like in your browser? is it `/projects/form/xxxx` or `projects/form?prjId=xxx`? You may need to look at `this.params.query` instead of `this.params` (it will require inspection to see, typically it appears empty even though its there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the parameter to your route definition in order for the mapping to work:

```
Router.route('/projects/form/:prjId', {
  name: 'projectForm',
  data: function() {
    return Projects.findOne(this.params.prjId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Duh. Thanks. Since this form is for both edit and add I appended a '?' . Works.